# With fluid_styled_content, how to create custom content elements in TYPO3 7.5 and 7 LTS?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.x, fluid-styled-content

I have been told it is a breeze to set up custom, structured content elements for the Backend in TYPO3 7.5, using the new fluid_styled_content system extension.

After looking at at `sysext/fluid_styled_content` and `sysext/backend`, I couldn't figure it out myself. Any hints?

Comment: Ah https://github.com/arnekolja/krbu_ce looks like a starting point

Comment: https://github.com/ervaude/fluid_styled_slider

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Information source: [fluid_styled_slider on Github](https://github.com/ervaude/fluid_styled_slider)

These information are also available here: [usetypo3 blog](https://usetypo3.com/custom-fsc-element.html)

The [official docs](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/master/en-us/) are online as well.

#### PageTSconfig

To make our content element appear in the wizard for new content elements, we have to add it via PageTSconfig

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common {
    elements {
        fs_slider {
            iconIdentifier = content-image
            title = LLL:EXT:fluid_styled_slider/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:wizard.title
            description = LLL:EXT:fluid_styled_slider/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:wizard.description
            tt_content_defValues {
                CType = fs_slider
            }
        }
    }
    show := addToList(fs_slider)
}
```

#### TCA

Now we need to tell TYPO3 what fields to show in the backend. Therefore we have to extend the tt_content TCA configuration.
This stuff is now done in the folder `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/`. Let's add our new CType first (this could also be done in `ext_tables.php`):

```php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
    [
        'LLL:EXT:fluid_styled_slider/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:wizard.title',
        'fs_slider',
        'content-image'
    ],
    'textmedia',
    'after'
);
```

Now we determine what fields to show for our CType:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['fs_slider'] = [
    'showitem' => '
        --palette--;' . $frontendLanguageFilePrefix . 'palette.general;general,
        --palette--;' . $languageFilePrefix . 'tt_content.palette.mediaAdjustments;mediaAdjustments,
        pi_flexform,
        --div--;' . $customLanguageFilePrefix . 'tca.tab.sliderElements,
        media
        '
];
```

#### TypoScript

The new CType `fs_slider` needs a rendering definition. This is rather simple:

```
tt_content {
    fs_slider < lib.fluidContent
    fs_slider {
        templateName = FluidStyledSlider
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                references.fieldName = media
            }
            20 = DanielGoerz\FluidStyledSlider\DataProcessing\FluidStyledSliderProcessor
        }
    }
}
```

The `lib.fluidContent` is not much more than the initialization of a `FLUIDCONTENT` object. We just change the template name
(make sure to at least add your template path to `lib.fluidContent.templateRootPaths`)
and specify which dataProcessors we are gonna use. Oh right, dataProcessors.

#### DataProcessors

Those are PHP classes that get the data before it is passed to the fluidtemplate. They can manipulate the data or add stuff to
be present in the template. The `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor`
for instance resolves all attached media elements for us, so we can access the FileReference objects in the view.
`DanielGoerz\FluidStyledSlider\DataProcessing\FluidStyledSliderProcessor` is a custom processor to illustrate how this works.

```php
class FluidStyledSliderProcessor implements DataProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * Process data for the CType "fs_slider"
     *
     * @param ContentObjectRenderer $cObj The content object renderer, which contains data of the content element
     * @param array $contentObjectConfiguration The configuration of Content Object
     * @param array $processorConfiguration The configuration of this processor
     * @param array $processedData Key/value store of processed data (e.g. to be passed to a Fluid View)
     * @return array the processed data as key/value store
     * @throws ContentRenderingException
     */
    public function process(ContentObjectRenderer $cObj, array $contentObjectConfiguration, array $processorConfiguration, array $processedData)
    {
        // Content of $processedData will be available in the template
        // It can be processed here to your needs.
        $processedData['slider']['width'] = 1000;
        return $processedData;
    }
```

However, DataProcessors are optional.

#### The Fluid template

The last piece in the puzzle is the actual template that receives the data processed by all specified DataProcessors in the end.
This is plain fluid as we know (and love) it:

```html
<html xmlns:f="http://xsd.helhum.io/ns/typo3/cms-fluid/master/ViewHelpers">
    <div class="fluid-styled-slider" style="width: {slider.width}px; margin: auto">
        <f:for each="{files}" as="file">
            <figure class="fluid-styled-slider-item">
                <f:image image="{file}" height="{data.imageheight}" width="{data.imagewidth}" alt="{file.properties.alt}" title="{file.properties.title}"/>
                <f:if condition="{file.properties.description}">
                    <figcaption>{file.properties.description}</figcaption>
                </f:if>
            </figure>
        </f:for>
    </div>
</html>
```

Of course we can use Layouts and Partials here as well. Note how `{data}` contains the tt_content row from the rendered
content element. `{files}` is added by the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor` and contains the attached media
as proper objects. `{slider.width}` is added by our own DataProcessor.

#### Optional: Preview in Page Module

We probably want some kind of preview for our editors in the page module. There are two notable possibilities to achieve this:

Fluid template via PageTSconfig

We can simply specify a fluid template to be rendered as preview in PageTSconfig:

```
web_layout.tt_content.preview.fs_slider = EXT:fluid_styled_slider/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/FluidStyledSlider.html
```

This template will receive all fields of the tt_content row directly. So `{header}` contains the header, `{bodytext}` contains the
bodytext and so on.

tt_content_drawItem Hook

If we want to do more sophisticated stuff like getting child records resolved, we can register to the `tt_content_drawItem` hook
like this:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['cms/layout/class.tx_cms_layout.php']['tt_content_drawItem']['fluid_styled_slider']
    = \DanielGoerz\FluidStyledSlider\Hooks\FsSliderPreviewRenderer::class;
```

Our class has to implement the `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface`.

```php
class FsSliderPreviewRenderer implements PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface
{
    /**
     * Preprocesses the preview rendering of a content element of type "fs_slider"
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView $parentObject Calling parent object
     * @param bool $drawItem Whether to draw the item using the default functionality
     * @param string $headerContent Header content
     * @param string $itemContent Item content
     * @param array $row Record row of tt_content
     * @return void
     */
    public function preProcess(PageLayoutView &$parentObject, &$drawItem, &$headerContent, &$itemContent, array &$row)
    {
        if ($row['CType'] === 'fs_slider') {
            if ($row['media']) {
                $itemContent .= '<h3>Fluid Styled Slider</h3>';
                $itemContent .= $parentObject->thumbCode($row, 'tt_content', 'media') . '<br />';
            }
            $drawItem = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever we write into `$itemContent` will be rendered in the page module inside our content element.

Comment: correct the reference to a real copy to avoid overriding `lib.fluidContent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did you have to write Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php and  Configuration/FlexForms/fs_slider_flexform.xml by hand as well?

Comment: What do you mean "by hand"? But yes, the TCA/Override stuff is missing, I will add it. The Flexform is completely optional since you might not need one in your content element.

Comment: By hand as in "did not appear automagically through some wizard" :-) Thanks!

Comment: Just wanna know if some knows how to enable normal content elements inside my custom element. For example: I want to create some sort of grouping element which can hold various other content elements. I can not figure out how to enable other content elements inside my custom element in the backend. Any hints?

Comment: @Markus Ideally open a new question. You can also look at extensions which already do this such as gridelements.