# TYPO3: Extension to run PHP code

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

This is more like a basic question:

How do I get an extension (by Extension Builder) to run a simple PHP code without adding a domain model and actions?

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi This version looks promising, but I still don't know how to include the output into my template. When adding a default html template to my extension it asks for a default controller, which doesn't and shouldn't exist.

Comment: Well, you can try to use `StandaloneView`, just instantiate it, `->setTemplateRootPaths(...)`, and then return result of `->render()`, but it would be more convinient, if you create normal Extbase Controller and get lot of magic out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there are 3 options:

- Create a content element which is answered here: [With fluid_styled_content, how to create custom content elements in TYPO3 7.5 and 7 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993534/with-fluid-styled-content-how-to-create-custom-content-elements-in-typo3-7-5-an)
- Create a plugin which is from the "old" kind, former called "pi_base".
- Create a plugin based on extbase.

I would still go with option number 3 and therefore you still will need an action. Having actions is good because of you add a 2nd variant, you can just use a 2nd action and there is not much additional code you need.

Having such an extension is fairly easy. One example I did lately was this extension: https://github.com/sup7even/mailchimp

In general you need:

**ext_localconf.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Sup7even.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Registration',
    array(
        'Form' => 'index,response,ajaxResponse'
    ),
    array(
        'Form' => 'index,response,ajaxResponse'
    )
);
```

**ext_tables.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Sup7.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Registration',
    'Mailchimp'
);
```

And the **RegistrationController**. By default, the first action will be called which is in this case *index*, therefore you need an `indexAction` and the Template must be `Templates/Registration/Index.html`.